# sorting an array List

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying to sort an list array that has Strings that contain Integers and letters but when i do it the regular way i get some wierd output:
relevant code:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();  
words.add("9 hello");
words.add("98 food");
words.add("105 cat");
words.add("2514 human");
words.add("3 pencil");
words.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

i am expecting :

```
"2514 human"
"105 cat"
"98 food"
"9 hello"
"3 pencil"
```

but i am getting something like this:

```
"98 food"
"9 hello"
"3 pencil"
"2514 human"
"105 cat"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: why exactly would you expect that outcome? you asked for a reversed alphabetical order, which seems exactly what you get

Comment: Why `2514 human` should be before `105 cat`?

Comment: You are sorting text **lexicographical**. You are not interpreting the numbers. `9...` is higher than `2...` no matter what comes after. You need to interpret the numbers as actual numbers instead of text to sort this in the way you want.

Comment: My guess, you'll need a composite object and do a reverse sort not on the word, but on the numerical value

Comment: your values are not an integer, it is compared as a string

Comment: @BLM-Maxx you need to sort descending based on the count

Comment: As a note to all of you that are not reading the full context. I am reviving an order of just the first 2 digits and has Notting to do with the alphabets as you see in the example I have 2 words that start with h and in between one that has a p

Comment: Use `Map<Integer, String>` instead of Arraylist, then it will be easier to get what you desire. Then sort on keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use comporator to solve your problem like this

Add this code inside you class

```
  private static Comparator<String> ORDER_MYLIST = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String d, String d1) {
                int first = Integer.parseInt(d.split(" ")[0]);//since you have space 
                int second = Integer.parseInt(d1.split(" ")[0]);
                return second - first;//change the order if you want
            }
};
```

Add this code in your calling function

```
Collections.sort(words, ORDER_MYLIST);
```

Output:

```
[2514 human, 105 cat, 98 food, 9 hello, 3 pencil]
```

Will be as you expect.

This link will give you better understanding on how comporator works
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: How about this code BLH-Maxx?

Comment: is this working on a 100k entry?

Comment: If the data is of same as your posted code it will work.

Comment: its a redis db with more or less 100k rows with a number and a word

Comment: Yes it will work

Comment: You can use this code as a util to call again to sort with your own custom order

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a class to represent the elements in the list.
For instance:

```
public class WordCount {
    public static final Comparator<WordCount> BY_COUNT;

    private static final Pattern PATTERN
            = Pattern.compile("\\s*([0-9]+)\\s+(.*)");

    public final int count;
    public final String word;

    public static WordCount parse(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(s);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Syntax error: " + s);
        }
        return new WordCount(
                Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
    }

    public WordCount(int count, String word) {
        this.count = count;
        this.word = word;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return count + " " + word;
    }

    static {
        BY_COUNT = (WordCount o1, WordCount o2) -> {
            int r = Integer.compare(o1.count, o2.count);
            if (r == 0) {
                r = o1.word.compareTo(o2.word);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }
}
```

Your code would then become:

```
    List<WordCount> words = new ArrayList<>();  
    words.add(WordCount.parse("9 hello"));
    words.add(WordCount.parse("98 food"));
    words.add(WordCount.parse("105 cat"));
    words.add(WordCount.parse("2514 human"));
    words.add(WordCount.parse("3 pencil"));
    words.sort(WordCount.BY_COUNT.reversed());
    words.forEach((wc) -> {
        System.out.println(wc);
    });
```

With the following result:

```
2514 human
105 cat
98 food
9 hello
3 pencil
```

Comment: Will this still work if I have let's say around 100k entrys?

Comment: @BLH-Maxx yes??

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom comparator to satisfy your requirement.
Java 8 solution:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();  
words.add("9 hello");
words.add("98 food");
words.add("105 cat");
words.add("2514 human");
words.add("3 pencil");

// Sort the existing list
words.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0]), Comparator.reverseOrder()));

// To create new sorted list
List<String> sortedWords = words.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0]), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

What you've got is exactly lexicographical order because not numbers are compared but their digits alphabetically.
If you want other behavior then you should consider implementing your own `Comparator` in which you'll parse the numbers.

Comment: As a note, the term is **lexicographical**. Also, the answer looks more like a comment than a full answer. A full answer would probably provide a ready solution, see [answer].

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice

Comment: You do realize that your answer makes no sense when there is a "p" in between 2 "h". Now that said it's more like the sorting is just taking the first digit and grouping all thebstarts with 1 then all that starts with 2 and so on